# If heat is energy, then why does cooling take energy when it should actually give energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, cooling

Since everything around us isn't absolute zero temperature, and it has heat/energy, then we should be able to use that energy (without temp' difference I mean) and by using that energy (for example converting it to electricity) cooling the area from which we took the heat from. So is there a way to convert heat without temp difference? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Because TINSSAAFL

Comment: It's not really free, we gained all that heat from the sun actually.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Look up something called the *Carnot efficiency*, among many others.

**There is no *extractable* heat energy without a temperature difference.**

For your apparent level of physics, it's probably best to take this as a fundamental principle that just is.

Comment: Ok i understand that my current level of physics is quiet low, but i want to learn and improve it, so can you tell me what to learn specific subject to understand it, i hate learning things as absolute rules i want to fully understant it, isnt that what sience is all about, so you sound like a smart guy, can you tell me where should i start? Can't go to colage atm unfortunatly:/ sorry about my english it's my second language

Comment: @user: Consider that here on the surface of the earth the atmosphere has a lot of pressure, over 2000 pounds per square foot or 23,000 pounds per square meter.  So why can't you use it to push your car along the highway for free?

Comment: Well i guess because its constant, its the same force all the time it doesnt change, just like you cant convert gravity to energy its a relative to where you set the zero point, but heat as i understand it is the atom / electrons moving in diffrent direction with some certain kinetic energy that is constant not relative

Comment: but heat isn't constant all the time only the avarage of it is constant, so if i have electrons moving all the time i should be able to direct them in a certain diracrtion, maybe with a magnetic field, lets say for example i have a coil that has some t temp'

Comment: that means that there is electrons moving all the time so if i aply a x magnetic field on it all the electrons should turn in a certain direcrion lets say clock wise, maybe some would go up or down but it doesn't matter because some would go around the coil (if i understand it correctly which i probably dont:/) and make a current.

Comment: Well i'm confused i guess my question is if i have an object with a negetive charge, electrons should move because it doesnt have zero temperature, then if i apply a magnetic field exactly as much as i need the electrons to turn around that object then i should be able to get a current am i? What am i getting wrong? Do electrons dont move all the time when they have a temperature above zero?

Comment: Why don't you want to answer me? Just say the reason i'll learn and get better next time, everyone got to have a starting point

Comment: @OlinLathrop lb/sq.foot or g/m2, please don't mix the unit systems that much.

Comment: @Min: For me it's easier to visualize that particular value in pounds per square foot or pounds per square meter.  Anyone that prefers other units can convert as they like.  That's what computers or calculators are for.  However, grams per square meter is not a unit of pressure, so it's always wrong.  If you want to stick to MKS units, use Newtons per square meter.

Answer (score 0):

> Heat is not an intrinsic property; that is, we cannot say that a
>   system "contains" a certain amount of heat. Heat is not the state
>   function , instead we can say that a certain amount of energy can be
>   transferred, into or out of the system in form of heat or work

*-Resnick, Halliday, Krane*

> Another way of looking at temperature is as an indicator of weather two bodies kept in contact will exchange energy as heat

*-Resnick, Halliday, Krane*

now from these two statement of a book are enough to give you your answer

Comment: Why can't we say that a system "contains" a certain amount of heat? Isn't heat just the kinetic energy of the particals in the system in time? Whats kelvin then?

Comment: Temperature is an indicator of weather?

Answer (score 0):

But cooling does release heat.

If you heat a chunk of iron to 200 Fahrenheit and place it in a closed insulated room as the iron cools it will heat the room.

You could say something contains a certain amount of heat as in the heat required to take it from absolute zero to its current state (including temperature).  But that does not mean much as the only way to extract that heat would be with a heat sink at a temperature of absolute zero and in real life that is not available.

No you don't get to just use the heat.  According to the second law of thermodynamics heat only flows from hot to cold.

If you want to convert heat to work a lower temperature heat sink is as important as the higher temperature heat source.

Answer (score 0):

I ask myself this question from time to time, and I don't know if answering now is necroing or what but I'd thought I give my 2c, since the same way I found this question others could.

In my mind cooling something is achieved by putting it in contact with something that is cooler than right? So if u put a block of ice in water it will cool down water and water will heat up the ice until it reaches a balance.

However to keep something cold you need to:
Keep it in contact with something so this temperature balance is achieve at the temperature you want the object to be,
Keep the object (and the environment it is in) isolated from the temperatures outside.
My guess is that the easiest way to do it is to pump cool air into a box, let it cool the object, then pump the warm air out so more cold air come in. Fridges I know use a gas to cool air I think? Just pass it through a cold tube and then into the fridge, while the air insider that would be warmer is taken into the cooling system again(probably? Just intuition at work here)
So the cooling of the air is not consuming electricity and does not require the fridge to be connected to an electrical outlet, but all the air movement via fans and stuff is what consumes energy. 
Maybe we could figure out to use the heat that we're taking from food and stuff in a fridge, to convert it back to energy to move the system itself, and that would make fridges more efficient? Or maybe the amount of heat we take doesn't compare to the amount we spend moving air constantly so it wouldn't matter.

Another thought I've had on the matter, let's say someone on the ISS needs to freeze something, he could go outside and take it out in the hatch to the vacuum outside and freeze it instantly right? It wouldn't require any energy to cool it because it's energy fleeing the object into the vacuum, the only energy used then would be the one the guy uses to take the object out, walking, floating, hatch opening, etc.

Comment: Fridges use compression and expansion to cool a working fluid (I'm rusty on my engineering thermodynamics but I believe it usually evaporates during the expansion releasing heat, and then is compressed again into a fluid).  As far as your ISS example goes I'm not sure how well that would work.  There is still potential to gain heat through radiation.

Comment: Fridges compress and expand gases to move heat from one location to the other. The act of doing this costs more energy in practice than what it can move in heat. As for space, a vacuum is one of the best thermal isolators there is. The heat will not rush from something taken into space, it would have to radiate away. If more radiation (like from the Sun) hits the object than what it generates from heat, it will heat up

Comment: $2c$ has a quite different meaning on this site :-)

Comment: @Jim "The act of doing this costs more energy in practice than what it can move in heat.".  Most refrigerators should have a [coefficient of performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_performance) greater than 1.  They will give more cooling work out than work required to run the system.

Comment: @JMac what I meant was the amount of heat out the back is greater than that lost on the inside. I apologize for using imprecise wording

Comment: @Jim No worries, I kinda assumed you meant that.  The nice thing about fridges is we have a huge heatsink of the outside environment (relative to in the fridge) so that is basically negligible from an energy perspective.